# Calling Scala Method from C++

Tags: c++, scala, java-native-interface

does anyone know if there is possibility to call a scala method from C++?

The reason I do this is I have a robust and powerful C++ back end, which could receives data and lambdas from scala front end. And I want to process these data using scala lambdas in the back end.

To be honest, the first thing came to my mind is JNI, which enables us to call java methods from C++ and vice versa. And I have tried whether I can use JNI to call scala method as well. The answer is NO. Take `java/lang/String` for example, I tried using JNI to get some methods from it. And only those java-specific methods can be got, like `toString`, `concat`, `charAt`, and those scala-specific methods are unavailable, including `apply`, `toLong`. The direct reason for this is that java reflection cannot capture scala-specific elements, see [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html).

And I have no other solutions for this. Any suggestions please?

Comment: While I believe you can actually figure out how the Scala code is turned into Java bytecode, and use this to write proper JNI calls, could I perhaps suggest a much simpler method of writing a Java wrapper for your Scala?

Comment: Well, you can't call special scala methods on String because: `type String        = java.lang.String` this is how it's defined. Scala specific methods come from implicit conversions.

Comment: @childofsoong although I don't quite like to involve a third language Java here, writing a Java wrapper seems to be an attractive solution.

Comment: @Łukasz well, good to know that. Thanks!

Comment: @Łukasz Well, yeah, if you were to try to call anything involving implicits through JNI, you'd have to do call the implicit methods explicitly, yes? (I'm really asking - I've never used JNI, just read about it a bit).

Comment: I haven't used JNI either but scala is compiled to jvm bytecode so I guess you would have to do similar thing to what compiler does, there are various rules and I don't think that it's worth it. You could do that java wrapper or even scala wrapper if you can make sure you don't use any of scala specific features that java doesn't have, then it should be compiled to something simple, without bunch of implicits and methods with $.

Comment: @Łukasz For me, I just want to process data, scala specific features seems to be less important. And besides JNI, maybe I can only think about running scala as a new process and data are transferred using IPC or socket between C++ and scala. I don't know which is better. There's a trade-off.